# Como actualizar datos mediante Modal, MVC AJAX?

Tags: php, ajax, mvc

Tengo un proyecto en donde debo actualizar los datos de cualquier usuario utilizando AJAX, aplicando el estilo de arquitectura MVC PHP, al momento que intenta hacer la actualizacion el Boton llamada Registrate que es del modal no realiza ninguna funcion.

- Adjunto el formulario el cual se muestran los datos del usuario y el boton que al momento de hacer clic muestra el modal.

```html
<form id="">
  <!-- Estructura del formulario -->
  <fieldset>
    <!-- Caja de texto para usuario -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <label class="sr-only" for="user">Tipo de Doc.</label>
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="" value="<?php echo ucfirst($_SESSION['tipo_documento']); ?>" readonly=»readonly»>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <label class="sr-only" for="user">N.º de Doc.</label>
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="" value="<?php echo ucfirst($_SESSION['documento']); ?>" readonly=»readonly»>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <label class="sr-only" for="user">Nombre</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="" value="<?php echo ucfirst($_SESSION['nombre']); ?>" readonly=»readonly»>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Div espaciador -->
    <div class="spacing-2"></div>

    <!-- Caja de texto para usuario -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <label class="sr-only" for="user">Email</label>
        <div class="input-group">
          <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></div>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="" value="<?php echo ucfirst($_SESSION['email']); ?>" readonly=»readonly»>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="sr-only" for="user">Telefono</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" name="" value="<?php echo ucfirst($_SESSION['telefono']); ?>" readonly=»readonly»>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<div class="row_ac">
  <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
    <div class="spacing-2"></div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#myModal">
      Actualizar
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

- En este formulario al momento de clickear el boton actualizar muestra un nuevo formulario para ingresar los nuevos datos y que permita actualizar.

```html
<!-- The Modal -->
<div class="modal" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <!-- Modal Header -->
      <div class="modal-header">
        <div class="widget-49-meeting-info">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Configuracion y Privacidad</h4>
          <span class="widget-49-meeting-time">Actualizar</span>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal"></button>
      </div>

      <!-- Modal body -->
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form id="nuevos_datos">
          <!-- Estructura del formulario -->
          <fieldset>
            <!-- Caja de texto para usuario -->
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col">
                <label class="sr-only" for="user">Tipo de Doc.</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                  <select name="tipo_documento" id="" class="form-control">
                    <option value="Cedula">Cedula</option>
                    <option value="Pasaporte">Pasaporte</option>
                    <option value="R.U.C">R.U.C</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col">
                <label class="sr-only" for="user">N.º de Doc.</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="documento" value="">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <label class="sr-only" for="user">Nombre</label>
              <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" value="">
              </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Div espaciador -->
            <div class="spacing-2"></div>

            <!-- Caja de texto para usuario -->
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col">
                <label class="sr-only" for="user">Email</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                  <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></div>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" value="">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="sr-only" for="user">Telefono</label>
                  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="telefono" value="">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Animacion de load (solo sera visible cuando el cliente espere una respuesta del servidor )-->
            <div class="row" id="load" hidden="hidden">
              <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4 col-md-2 col-md-offset-5">
                <img src="img/load.gif" width="100%" alt="">
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 center text-accent">
                <span>Validando información...</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mt-4 text-center>
              <p class=" ZGwn1">Al registrarte, aceptas nuestras <a href="#" tabindex="0" target="_blank">Condiciones</a>, la <a href="#" tabindex="0" target="_blank">Política de datos</a> y la <a href="#" tabindex="0" target="_blank">Política de cookies</a>.</p>
            </div>
            <!-- Fin load -->
          </fieldset>
          <!-- Modal footer -->
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
              <div class="spacing-2"></div>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" name="button" id="actualizar">Registrate</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

- Los ¨Nuevos datos que se envian¨ los realizo mediante AJAX, no se si estarán bien

```javascript
$('#actualizar').click(function() {
  var form = $('#nuevos_datos').serialize();

  $.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'controller/actualizarController.php',
    data: form,

    success: function(data) {
      $('#nuevos_datos').html(data);
    }

  });
});
```

- Tener en cuenta que se aplica la arquitectura MVC mediante la carpeta controller y al archivo actualizarController.php

```php
<?php
$tipo_documento = $_POST["tipo_documento"];
$documento = $_POST["documento"];
$nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
$telefono = $_POST["telefono"];
$email = $_POST["email"];

if ($_POST["id"] != 0) {
    require_once "../model/usuario.php";

    parent::actualizarRegistro(
        $tipo_documento,
        $documento,
        $nombre,
        $telefono,
        $email
    );
} else {
    echo "error_1";
}
?>
```

- En la carpeta Model tengo creado un archivo llamado usuario.php, en la cual se hara la consulta para almanacenar los nuevos datos mediante la funcion declarada.
- OJO: solamente pongo el id 30 Porque solamente estoy haciendo la prueba con un solo usuario pero apesar de eso no me permite actualizar sus datos.

```php
public function actualizarRegistro($tipo_documento, $documento, $nombre, $telefono, $email)
{
    // establezco conexion con la base de datos.
    parent::conectar();

    // la palabra filtrar sirve no enviar caracteres absurdos

    $tipo_documento = parent::filtrar($tipo_documento);
    $documento = parent::filtrar($documento);
    $nombre  = parent::filtrar($nombre);
    $telefono = parent::filtrar($telefono);
    $email = parent::filtrar($email);

    parent::query('UPDATE usuarios SET tipo_documento="'.$tipo_documento.'", 
       documento="'.$documento.'", nombre="'.$nombre.'", telefono="'.$telefono.'", 
      email="'.$email.'", WHERE id=30');
}
```

- Agrego unos detalles adicionales para que pueda ser entendido un poco mas el codigo, en mi carpeta model existe una ruta llamada conexion, dentro del archivo se tiene codificado lo siguiente

```php
public function actualizarRegistro($consulta)
{
    return $actualizarRegistro = mysqli_num_rows($this->mysqli->query($consulta));
}
```

Espero por favor que me puedan ayudar con las correciones ya que llevo tiempo y no he podido resolver. quedo agradecido con su gentil ayuda y aporte. SALUDOS.

Comment: De momento no cierras bien el atributo `class` de esta línea:  `<div class="mt-4 text-center>`... Te faltan unas comillas despues de `text-center`.

Answer (score 0):

Primero debes arreglar la falta de comillas en esta línea después del `text-center`:

```html
<div class="mt-4 text-center>
```

Luego, debes verificar lo que estás pasando en la llamada ajax del parámetro `data`, concretamente los datos serializados del formulario, que en mis pruebas se me muestran así:

```
"tipo_documento=Cedula&amp;documento=&amp;nombre=&amp;email=&amp;telefono="
```

Y si te fijas en tu PHP que lo recoge, `actualizarController.php` tienes puesto este condicional para devolver los datos:

```php
if ($_POST["id"] != 0) {
```

que si te das cuenta, `id` **no aparece en los datos serializados** por lo tanto seguramente te da un error de PHP que no se muestra en pantalla, sino que deberias encontrarlo en el log de errores de tu dominio, y acaba sin devolver nada.

Mira a ver si es eso el problema y nos cuentas.

Comment: Hola muchas gracias, elimine la clase <div class="mt-4 text-center> ya que no sirve, segundo lugar sigue sin funcionar el envio de datos, la verdad necesito que me ayuden por favor aplique la siguiente forma en ajax pero sigue sin hacer nada  `$('#actualizar').click(function ()
{

  $.ajax(
    {
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'controller/actualizarController.php'
    })

    .done(function(data){
      $('#nuevos_datos').html(data);
     });
});`  En actualizarController.php Elimine la condicion. Por favor si me puedes ayudar con un correo ya que no encuentro solucion.

Comment: Seguro que hace algo, lo que ocurre es que debes tener los errores deshabilitados en la configuración de tu servidor.  Tendrias que buscar y encontrar el archivo de errores log de tu servidor para ver lo que te dice y que errores te muestra.  Se puede llamar `error_log` o `dominio.com.error.log` o cosas parecidas, y deberia estar en el mismo lugar donde estan los logs normales de tu dominio, normalmente tambien una carpeta llamada `logs` (esto varia segun el entorno donde estes).  No ayudamos externamente, lo hacemos todo aqui para el bien de la comunidad, sino no tendria sentido y te cobraria

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, espero no incomodar. estas son las lineas  [Tue Jan 18 09:54:38.043201 2022] [php7:warn] [pid 16432:tid 1824] [client ::1:61801] PHP Warning:  Declaration of Usuario::actualizarRegistro($tipo_documento, $documento, $nombre, $telefono, $email) should be compatible with Conexion::actualizarRegistro($consulta) in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\**\\model\\usuario.php on line 171, referer: http://localhost/**/index.php

Comment: Si tienes lineas de error mejor que edites tu pregunta agregandolas al final o al principio, como prefieras, asi lo veran todos y podras recibir mejor ayuda

Comment: Vaya, ese error me pierde un poco... supongo que ambas clases estan vinculadas de algun modo y no le gusta que esa funcion se llame igual pero tenga parámetros distintos... ¿tienen que tener el mismo nombre de funcion?  Si lo cambias quizas consigas superar ese error (hasta el siguiente y a ver que es)

Comment: muchas gracias revisare mas detalles.